# How does LazyFrames from OpenAI's baselines save memory?

Tags: python, numpy, openai-gym, stable-baselines

OpenAI's baselines use the following code to return a `LazyFrames` instead of a concatenated numpy array to save memory. The idea is to take the advantage of the fact that a numpy array can be saved at different lists at the same time as lists only save a reference not object itself. However, in the implementation of `LazyFrames`, it further saves the concatenated numpy array in `self._out`, in that case if every `LazyFrames` object has been invoked at least once, it will always save a concatenated numpy array within it, which does not seem to save any memory at all. Then what's the point of `LazeFrames`? Or do I misunderstand anything?

```py
class FrameStack(gym.Wrapper):
    def __init__(self, env, k):
        """Stack k last frames.

        Returns lazy array, which is much more memory efficient.

        See Also
        --------
        baselines.common.atari_wrappers.LazyFrames
        """
        gym.Wrapper.__init__(self, env)
        self.k = k
        self.frames = deque([], maxlen=k)
        shp = env.observation_space.shape
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(shp[:-1] + (shp[-1] * k,)), dtype=env.observation_space.dtype)

    def reset(self):
        ob = self.env.reset()
        for _ in range(self.k):
            self.frames.append(ob)
        return self._get_ob()

    def step(self, action):
        ob, reward, done, info = self.env.step(action)
        self.frames.append(ob)
        return self._get_ob(), reward, done, info

    def _get_ob(self):
        assert len(self.frames) == self.k
        return LazyFrames(list(self.frames))

class LazyFrames(object):
    def __init__(self, frames):
        """This object ensures that common frames between the observations are only stored once.
        It exists purely to optimize memory usage which can be huge for DQN's 1M frames replay
        buffers.

        This object should only be converted to numpy array before being passed to the model.

        You'd not believe how complex the previous solution was."""
        self._frames = frames
        self._out = None

    def _force(self):
        if self._out is None:
            self._out = np.concatenate(self._frames, axis=-1)
            self._frames = None
        return self._out

    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        out = self._force()
        if dtype is not None:
            out = out.astype(dtype)
        return out

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._force())

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self._force()[i]

    def count(self):
        frames = self._force()
        return frames.shape[frames.ndim - 1]

    def frame(self, i):
        return self._force()[..., I]
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually came here trying to understand how this saved any memory at all! But you mention that the lists store references to the underlying data, while the numpy arrays store copies of that data, and I think you are correct about that.

To answer your question, you are right! When `_force` is called, it populates the `self._out` item with a numpy array, thereby expanding the memory. But *until* you call `_force` (which is called in any of the API functions of the `LazyFrame`), `self._out` is `None`. So the idea is to not call `_force` (and therefore, don't call any of the `LazyFrames` methods) until you need the underlying data, hence the warning in its doc string of "This object should only be converted to numpy array before being passed to the model".

Note that when `self._out` gets populated by the array, it also clears the `self._frames`, so that it doesn't store duplicate information (thereby harming its whole purpose of storing only as much as it needs).

Also, in the same file, you'll find the `ScaledFloatFrame` which carries this doc string:

> ```
>     Scales the observations by 255 after converting to float.
>     This will undo the memory optimization of LazyFrames,
>     so don't use it with huge replay buffers.
> ```